# LuaLaTeX code should generate an error, yet doesn't

Tags: tables, luatex, lua

I'm trying to learn a bit more about LuaLaTeX and came across this [introduction](https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2020/06/20/luatex-intro.html). The author claims that the following code does not work:

```
% this code will not work
\directlua{
    tex.print("\\begin{tabular}{lll}")
    tex.print("1 & a & Test A \\\\")
    tex.print("2 & b & Test B \\\\")
    tex.print("\\end{tabular}")
}
```

I have, however, tried this on my local machine, and compiling using `latexmk -pdflatex test.tex` works just fine. Furthermore, the table generated by LaTeX looks identical to the one generated via Lua. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  Table generated by Lua:
  \directlua{
    tex.print("\\begin{tabular}{lll}")
    tex.print("1 & a & Test A \\\\")
    tex.print("2 & b & Test B \\\\")
    tex.print("\\end{tabular}")
  }

  Table generated by \LaTeX
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    1 & a & Test A \\
    2 & b & Test B \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why is my code *not* generating an error?

Comment: This is because `\\ ` is etex `\protected` (robust), so it is not expanded before passing to LuaTeX. You can observe the same thing with `\immediate\write16{\\ <- not expanded}` which shows up verbatim.

Answer (score 4):

The page that you reference would have been correct when written but in recent years more latex commands have been made robust and in the case of `\\`  that is done with e-tex `\protected` (not the LaTeX  `\DeclareRobustCommand` mechanism) as such it stays as `\\`  in `\directlua`

Specifically this change was made in January 2020

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/203